# Codeigniter 2 not charges the functions of model

Tags: function, codeigniter, model

I have a problem with this:

$this->load->model('name_model');
$this->name_model->function();

Codeigniter detects model charge but not charge the function. The function in the model is very basic, but fails.

Any ideas.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean by charge? what is fails? does it have any error?

Comment: Provide model and controller code for us to understand the issue.

Comment: No detects the function. The problem is: I have a helper but Its not charge the function of the model. I use codeigniter 2.0 but the hooks and custom libraries not working